# Converting a row of data into a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a single row data frame like this:

```
X1       X2                                           X3

1        [['1','2','3'], ['4','6','5'], ['7','8']]    ['9','10','11','12','13']
```

I would like create a new dataframe from that using columns X2 and X3 that looks like this:

```
ID Group

1  A

2  A

3  A

4  B

5  B

6  B

7  C

8  C

9  D

10 D

11 D

12 D

13 D
```

So each number in the dataframe is grouped by the square brackets in the orignal dataframe.
Can anyone recommend a good way of doing this in R.

Comment: Sorted that typo

Comment: So in the new dataframe, each row is the ID in one column then the group in the second column

Comment: Yes it is, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to split the 'X2' at the `,` followed by the `]`, concatenate with 'X3', extract the numeric elements with `str_extract_all` into a `list`, `stack` it to a two column `data.frame`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- c(strsplit(df1$X2, "\\],\\s*")[[1]], df1$X3)
out <- stack(setNames(str_extract_all(v1, "\\d+"), LETTERS[1:4]))
names(out) <- c("ID", "Group")
out
#   ID Group
#1   1     A
#2   2     A
#3   3     A
#4   4     B
#5   6     B
#6   5     B
#7   7     C
#8   8     C
#9   9     D
#10 10     D
#11 11     D
#12 12     D
#13 13     D
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols  = -X1) %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep="(?<=\\]),\\s*") %>%
  transmute(Group = LETTERS[row_number()], ID = value) %>%
  mutate(ID = str_extract_all(ID, "\\d+")) %>% 
  unnest(c(ID))
# A tibble: 13 x 2
#   Group ID   
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 A     1    
# 2 A     2    
# 3 A     3    
# 4 B     4    
# 5 B     6    
# 6 B     5    
# 7 C     7    
# 8 C     8    
# 9 D     9    
#10 D     10   
#11 D     11   
#12 D     12   
#13 D     13
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = 1L, X2 = "[['1','2','3'], ['4','6','5'], ['7','8']]", 
    X3 = "['9','10','11','12','13']"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```